# How to use UINavigation with MSDynamicsDrawerViewController

Tags: ios, push, segue

I'm using MSDynamicsDrawerViewController on my Project, and following the example that they provide I'm able to make it work perfectly.

On their example using StoryBoard the MSDynamicsDrawerViewController needs to be set as the "is The Initial View Controller", and from there you load your Main View.

Now on my Main View Controller I'm triying to do a Push to another View. So what I do its the following:

- Editor--> Embed In --> Navigation Controller, to add Navigation Controller to Main View Controller.
- The I press control and drag the line to the other View Controller. And I select "Push" as the type of Segue.

This is the error that I get.

> Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.

I according to what I researched and I needed a Navigation Controller selected, and I have it.

Not sure what to do.

Comment: Will I need to implement a Custom Segue?

Comment: When I setup the Navigation View Controller on my AppDelegate I have

'self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.dynamicsDrawerViewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    [self.window addSubview:self.windowBackground];
    [self.window sendSubviewToBack:self.windowBackground];'